# Where can i get a lot of exercises about convergence/divergence of series made step by step?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm loking for a site or something where i can get a lot of exercises about series. I was searching here but a lot of answers are not complete.

I must study and i want to see a bunch of hard examples fully made with all their details in order to inspire me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the book I learned series from was Knopp, Infinite Series, Theory and Application. It's not a dedicated problem/exercise book, but it does contain a good bunch of examples, and the treatment is beautiful. I found it inspiring, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Calculus 7th edition by Stewart" ([https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-7th-James-Stewart/dp/0538497815](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538497815)) is helpful with the chapter 12 disclosing infinite sequences and series.